# Using asunc with asynchronous functions for unit tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, asynchronous, mocha.js

I'm trying to setup some unit tests this way using mocha. But, it doesn't log any thing, even when I remove ̀ setTimeout`.

http://pastebin.com/yPWL6Tvc

Here's the mocha's output:

[image]

What's wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't define the callback `done`. Line 41 of your pastebin should probably have a callback parameter at the end. Having said that, simply using mocha's callback functionality might be a better idea for you, instead of using async.